# Definition of Sobolev spaces: Fourier transform of tempered distribution

Tags: sobolev-spaces

I consider in "McLean - Strongly Elliptic Systems and Boundary Integral Equations" the definition of the Sobolev space for $s \in \mathbb R$
$$
H^s(\mathbb R^n) := \{u \in \mathcal S^*(\mathbb R^n) \colon \mathcal J^s u \in L^2(\mathbb R^n) \}
$$
with the inner product
$$
(u,v)_{H^s(\mathbb R^n)} := (\mathcal J^s u, \mathcal J^s v)_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)}
$$
and the induced norm
$$
\|u\|_{H^s(\mathbb R^n)} := \|\mathcal J^s u\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)}.
$$

$\mathcal J^s \colon \, \mathcal S(\mathbb R^n) \to \mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ is the Bessel potential of order $s \in \mathbb R$ defined by
$$
\mathcal J^s u(x) := \int_{\mathbb R^n}(1 + |\xi|^2)^{\frac s 2} \hat u(\xi) \mathrm e^{\mathrm i 2 \pi \xi \cdot x} \mathrm d\xi \quad \text{ for } x \in \mathbb R^n
$$
where $\hat u$ is the Fourier transform of $u,\,$ $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ is the Schwartz space and $\mathcal S^*(\mathbb R^n)$ is the space of tempered distributions.
The Bessel potential has a natural extension to $\mathcal J^s \colon \, \mathcal S^*(\mathbb R^n) \to \mathcal S^*(\mathbb R^n)$ by
$$
\langle \mathcal J^s u, \varphi \rangle := \langle u,\mathcal J^s \varphi \rangle.
$$
My question is:
If $u \in H^s(\mathbb R^n)$ and so $J^s u \in L^2 (\mathbb R^n),$ is then $\hat u$ a function for all $s \in \mathbb R?$
In McLean (and many other books) the Sobolev norm has the integral representation
$$
\|u\|^2_{H^s(\mathbb R^n)} = \int_{\mathbb R^n}(1 + |\xi|^2)^{s} | \hat u(\xi)|^2 \mathrm d\xi
$$
for all $s \in \mathbb R$ and so $\hat u$ must be function. But I haven't a proof for this. Is there anybody who can help me?

Thanks.

Comment: See the comment for the first answer.

Comment: ps usethe  answer only for answers , you can edit the question if you want to give more information ( highly recomended)

Answer (score 0):

HINT: One has $ (1+\lvert\xi\rvert^2)^\frac{s}{2}\ge 1$. This, and [Plancherel's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem).

**EDIT**: This actually addresses another question, namely, "When $s\ge 0$, is it true that $u\in H^s$ implies $u\in L^2$?". Indeed, when $s<0$, it might well happen that $u\in H^s$ is not a function. (The Dirac delta $\delta$ is such that $\delta\in H^{-s}$ for $s> \frac{n}{2}$).

What is *always* true, however, is that the Fourier transform $\hat{u}$ is a function if $u\in H^s$. This can be seen as follows. By definition, the pointwise product 
$$(1+\lvert \xi\rvert^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}\hat{u}=\hat{v}$$
is a function, that is, it belongs to $L^1_\mathrm{loc}$. Now we observe that any pointwise product $f\cdot g$ with $f\in L^1_\mathrm{loc}$ and $g\in L^\infty_{\mathrm{loc}}$ is an element of $L^1_\mathrm{loc}$. Apply this observation to $f=\hat{v}$ and $g=(1+\lvert \xi\rvert^2)^{\frac{-s}{2}}$.

Comment: Let $u \in H^s(\mathbb R^n)$ be and so $g:= \mathcal J^s u \in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ and so we get
$$
\langle \mathcal J^s u, \varphi \rangle = \langle g, \varphi \rangle_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)} = \langle \mathcal F g, \mathcal \varphi \rangle_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)} = \langle w_s \hat u, \hat \varphi \rangle _{L^2(\mathbb R^n)}
$$
with $w_s(\xi) := (1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac s 2}$ and $\mathcal F g = \mathcal F \mathcal J^s u = w_s \mathcal F u = w_s \hat u \in L^2(\mathbb R^n).$

Comment: I don't see that $\hat u$ is a function. We only know that $h:=w_s \hat u \in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$  is a function.

EDIT: In the first comment should be $\mathcal F \varphi$ in the third from left term.

Comment: @eierkopf: $w_s$ is never zero, you can divide.

Comment: It was too long to answer in the comment. See my new answer below.

Comment: Does somebody know some corrections or improvements?

Answer (score 0):

We know from the comments above for $h:= w_s \hat u \in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ that it holds
$$
\langle w_s \hat u, \varphi \rangle = \langle \hat u, w_s \varphi \rangle = \langle h, \varphi \rangle_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)}
$$
for all $\varphi \in S(\mathbb R^n)$ and if we choose $\varphi := w_{-s} \psi \in \mathcal S (\mathbb R^n)$ with $\psi \in \mathcal S (\mathbb R^n)$ it follows
$$
\langle w_s \hat u, w_{-s} \psi \rangle = \langle \hat u, w_s w_{-s} \psi \rangle = \langle \hat u, \psi \rangle = \langle h, w_{-s} \psi \rangle_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)} = \langle w_{-s} h, \psi \rangle_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)}.
$$
That means we get for all $\psi \in  \mathcal S (\mathbb R^n)$ the relation
$$
\langle \hat u, \psi \rangle = \langle w_{-s} h, \psi \rangle_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)}.
$$
So $\hat u$ has the representation by the function $\xi \mapsto w_{-s}(\xi) h(\xi) = (1+|\xi|^2)^{-\frac s 2} h(\xi)$ with $h \in L^2(\mathbb R^n).$
I think that is the proof I wanted. Any improvements?

Comment: It's much easier than that. Take $u\in H^s$. By definition you have $(1+\lvert\xi\rvert^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}\hat{u}\in L^2$. In particular, $\hat{v}=(1+\lvert\xi\rvert^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}\hat{u}$ is a function. But then $\hat{u}=(1+\lvert\xi\rvert^2)^{-\frac{s}{2}}\hat{v}$ is a function as well. My "community wiki" answer is probably misleading, I am sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I don't understand why you can see easily that $\hat u$ is a function. Because we only know that your $\hat v = w_s \hat u$ has a representation as a function and then I have to prove that $\hat u$ has also got a representation of a function.

Comment: I updated my community wiki answer. Hopefully it is clearer now.